# Why do I get "Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Grammar::parameterize() must be of the type array, string given"

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I got this error in production, when I am using MySQL instead of SQLite. I got an error that I never got before.

When I try to send data through my form, I get this exception :

```
Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Grammar::parameterize() must be of the type array, string given
```

Here is the code I use to put the data inside the databse:

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        if(isset($request['recommended'])) {
            $request['recommended'] = true;
        } else {
            $request['recommended'] = false;
        }

        $validated = $request->validate([
            'title' => 'required|string',
            'recommended' => 'required|boolean',
            'us' => 'string',
            'ca' => 'string'
        ]);
        $item = new Item();
        $item->fill($validated);
        $item->save();
        $validated['item_id'] = $item->id;
        ItemLink::create($validated);
        return redirect()->route('items.index');
    }
```

The error seems to happen on the line $item->save();

I tried to dump my $validated variable, here is its content :

```
array:4 [
  "title" => "Echo Show 8"
  "recommended" => false
  "us" => "asdaksjdkasj"
  "ca" => "asdasdsad"
]
```

I get that I should pass an array, but I just don't understand why and how..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was in the Item model. I had a custom protected property, named $attributes which was an array. I used it to attach some properties when I was fetching the object.

However, for a reason that I still don't understand, Laravel tried to use it as a database value. I just had to put the property as "public" and everything worked properly.